# How to count elements inside array/object on PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, count

I have this array being sent to my view

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [emg_id] => 2
            [fkit] => 1
            [door] => 
        )

)
```

I would like to count how many elements are empty, NULL, or '0'.

I tried using `count` but it always returns '1', instead of counting all of the elements, so I can later determine which satisfy my conditions above.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// number of "null" elements
echo count(array_filter((array) $array[0], 'is_null'));
```

There are some other `is_*()`-functions built-in, that may help you for example to count the number of strings (and so on).

To test, if an element is (e.g.) `0`, I suggest to use an anonymous function

```
echo count(array_filter((array) $array[0], function ($item) {
  return $item === 0;
}));
```

The other cases are similar.

Comment: thx @kingcrunch -- how about the 'is_null' in your first example: I get an error message saying the second parameter should be long, string given -- is your 'is_null' just a placeholder?

Comment: :) - good xkcd BTW - looks like 'empty' also returns an error -- "The second argument, 'empty', should be a valid callback"

Comment: ... `empty` is a language construct -.- However, the idea is clear? :D

Comment: yes thanks for helping -- looks like using `array_filter` without callback covers most of my needs

Answer (score 1):

loop through them and count.

```
function loopMe($array, $value) {
    $num = 0;
    foreach($array as $key=>$val) {
        if($val == $value)
        $num++;
    }
    return $num;
}


$ar = array (
    array (
        "emg_id" => 2
        "fkit" => 1
        "door" => null));
$num = loopMe($ar[0], null);
```